# extraneous css file request generated

Tags: theming

Something within my site is generating a request to a css file called "none". It is using the path of our theme. Our theme does not have any such style sheet called as part of our stylesheets array.

Our definition:

stylesheets[all][] = css/mods.css

stylesheets[all][] = css/main.css

request on page load:

/sites/all/themes/our_bootstrap/css/none

Since there is no such file, a 404 is served for that file. Where can I look to track down what is generating the request?

Comment: grep around for all calls to `drupal_add_css()` eg, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7

Comment: I would grep for the string 'none' instead. The file may be being added in a dozen different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have something like `url('none');` specified for a background (or list image, etc.) in your stylesheets.

Comment: That was it. I needed to use "background: none;" instead.